# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined in Javascript while submitting form

Tags: javascript, jquery, python-3.x, web.py

I'm trying to make a social networking mini web app using python web.py module.
I made a registration form in html, but when I fill the details and submit them, the browser console shows the following output:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).ready(...) is not a function
at scripty.js:22
loaded
jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (scripty.js:4)
at e (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
at t (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
```

I've searched for similar problems but their solutions doesn't seem to work for this case.

Here is my "scripty.js" file code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log("loaded");

    $.material.init();

    $(document).on("submit", "#register-form", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("form submitted");

        let form = $('#register-form').serialize(); //get the form data

        //send an ajax request over to the route /postregisteration
        $.ajax({
            url: '/postregisteration',
            type: 'POST',
            data: form,
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    });
})();
```

And here is the controller.py file code in python

```
import web
from Models import RegisterModel


urls = (
    '/', 'Home',
    '/register', 'Register',
    '/postregistration', 'PostRegistration'
)

render =  web.template.render("Views/Templates", base="MainLayout")

app = web.application(urls, globals())


# Classes/Routes
# Each class will be controlling a route

class Home:
    def GET(self):
        return render.Home()

class Register:
    def GET(self):
        return render.Register()

class PostRegistration:
    def POST(self):
        data = web.input()
        print(data.username)

        reg_model = RegisterModel.RegisterModel.insert_user(data)
        return data.username


if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run()
```

After clicking submit, it just prints 
"loaded" and shows the error on browser console.

But it must also show 
"form submitted".

Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: Well, in your code you're calling a function called `init` from the object `$.material` but it seems that `$.material` is undefined. You have to look into why you're calling it, what it is etc. Did you forget to load that script? Do you use it etc? The issue here has nothing to do with Python, it's your client-side javascript that is malfunctioning.

Comment: Actually I'm doing a course on python, and I'm new to JS so I just copied this JS code to get data from the html form. I searched the whole project but there is no "$material" found. I don't know why the instructor wrote, I think its is problem of jquery. Is there any other way to get data from html form in in python using web.py

Comment: Don't just copy random JS code; the last line says `})();` which causes the first error; change that to `});`. Next, remove the `$.material.init();` line, you don't need it.

Comment: I fixed it by copying new files/structure of material and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the last line of the JS you've shown:

From

```
})();
```

to

```
});
```

That fixes your first error `... is not a function`.

For the second error, that means `$.material` is `undefined`. Either remove it (if you're not using material design) or make sure the corresponding plugin is available.

Answer (score 1):

Here's your script with the end line bug fixed, material removed and with comments added that explain what each line does.

```
// Wait until the page has fully loaded before applying the script
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Bind a function to the submit form
    $(document).on("submit", "#register-form", function (e) {
        // Prevent the default form post behavior to prevent the page from reloading
        e.preventDefault();

        // Get the form data
        var form = $('#register-form').serialize(); 

        // Send an ajax request over to the route /postregisteration
        $.ajax({
            url: '/postregisteration',
            type: 'POST',
            data: form,
            success: function (response) {
                console.log("form submitted");
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: They shouldn't be. Here's a fiddle that works (of course "postregisteration" doesn't exists there so the ajax request fails, but the javascript code is functional): https://jsfiddle.net/insats/8bc19ap7/11

Comment: Yah, it is fixed now, Thanks, I've stuck here for a while.